# SUMIFS for text and date

Tags: excel

I am looking to return the sum of C (price) using the layout shown in J,K,L by month.  The lookup would be by customer (3M) and Part Group (420) for this example.  Every month should return zero for 3M expect August should read $255.

Please help and see what I am missing

[image: Sample layout]

Comment: Suggest you use the Function Wizard to get your arguments in the correct locations.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of SUMIFS() is the column which you would want to sum. So I presume in your case it's column C, and so SUMIFS($B$2:$B$50000,......) should be changed to SUMIFS($C$2:$C$50000,......).

An easier workaround for the month matching would be to use =MONTH() function. =MONTH(date) returns the month index. 1-12 for months Jan to Dec. You could cells starting E2 as E2=MONTH(D2) and so on till end of column E. Add the indices for the months in a column adjacent to I and use that for SUMIFS